# Solve $\sqrt{x-2} \geq -1$

Tags: inequality

I tried to solve the inequality by squaring both sides. Thus in the answer $x$ belonged to $[3,\infty)$. How can I solve it to get the answer $[2,\infty)$?

Comment: You can't squaring both sides to an inequality without any condition. For example, $-1 < 0$ is true but $(-1)^2 < 0^2$ is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square roots, when defined, are always non-negative, and therefore always greater than $-1$. So rather than a question of when the inequality is satisfied, this becomes a question of when it even makes sense.

Also, squaring both sides of an inequality is dangerous, as things that were negative are now positive, but things that were positive stay positive. If you know both sides were positive, or both sides were negative before squaring, then that's fine. But when one side is positive and one side is negative, then you can in general say nothing about the relationship between the squares.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by inspection! We cannot have a negative in a square root so the smallest $x$ could be is $2$ which means $\sqrt{2-2}=\sqrt{0}\ge -1$ so must work for all other $x\ge2$. So this gives the interval $[2,\infty]$!

Comment: $\sqrt 0 \not \ge 1$

Answer (score 0):

To begin, the square root is defined only for non-negative numbers; so here we must have $x\geq2$.

Furthermore, the square root of a non-negative number is non-negative by definition.

Hence all $x\geq2$ are solutions to the equation.

Answer (score 0):

If $\sqrt{x-2}$ is defined, i.e. if $x\ge 2$, $ \sqrt{x-2}\ge 0\enspace\text{(by definition)}\;>-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have $$\sqrt{x-2}\geq 0>-1$$ so your equation is fulfilled for all $x$ with $$x\geq 2$$